# www-data can upload a file but cant move it after the upload action

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, permissions, www-data

I am currently running Apache and PHP on Ubuntu. I have a page where a user is supposed to upload a profile image. The action on the backend is supposed to work like this:

1. Upload file to user directory -- WORKS!
2. Refer to the uploaded file and create a thumbnail in directory thumbs -- DOES NOT WORK

www-data has write access to directory thumbs. My guess is that www-data for some reason does not have proper access to the file that was uploaded.

UPLOADED FILE PERMISSIONS

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 47057 Feb  8 23:24 0181c6e0973eb19cb0d98521a6fe1d9e71cd6daa.jpg
```

THUMBS DIRECTORY PERMISSIONS

```
drwxr-sr-x 2 www-data www-data  4096 Feb  8 23:23 thumbs
```

Im at lost here. I'm new to Ubuntu as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

SOLVED:

I was using a function imagecreatefromjpeg() and needed to add run the following:

apt-get install php5-gd

So it turned out not to be a permissions issue.

Thanks for the suggestion and I am sure they will come in handy in the near future!

Comment: What's the error you are getting in the php log files? (Possibly just the standard apache error.log)

Comment: Please post the error and also let us know how the file is being uploaded. Is the place where the file is being uploaded in the docroot?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be like a permission problem. If so, you can do the following to confirm.

Change the destination folder to `/tmp/`. This is world-writable folder. It the thumbs creation succeeded. Then, it is likely that `www-data` is not able to write to thumbs folder. Another check is to change the folder you are reading from. You can also read from `/tmp/`. It if works, then your `www-data` user is having troubles accessing the folders.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a possible candidate for selinux stepping on your feet.  Try

```
echo 0 >/selinux/enforce
```

and repeat the test.